# How can I get screen width and height dimensions from diagonal?

Tags: display, specifications

All gadget specs sites specify screen dimension as diagonal unit, no width and height in inches:

```
Display 4.95 in (126 mm) 
1920×1080 px (445 ppi)
```

For example, GMD (Google Material Design) site [reads](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html):

> screen density = screen width (or height) in pixels / **screen width** (or height) **in inches**

And I simply cannot find a gadget screen width (or height) in inches anywhere. Only diagonal unit is everywhere.

Where may I get screen width (or height) of gadgets displays in inches?

Comment: If you know the aspect ratio (usually 4:3, for TVs etc also 16:9), it's easy to calculate

Answer (score 2):

That's a matter of simple maths. You know screen dimensions in pixels, so you can calculate diagonal length in pixels and calculate pixels-to-inches ratio.
For example my main PC screen is 24" with resolution of 1920×1200. Its diagonal measured in pixels is:

> d<sub>px</sub><sup>2</sup> = 1920<sup>2</sup> + 1200<sup>2</sup> = 5126400
>
> d<sub>px</sub> = 2264.15 px

Now I know its diagonal both in inches and pixels. I can calculate pixel density (pixels per inch, PPI):

> ppi = d<sub>px</sub> / d<sub>inch</sub> = 2264.15 / 24 = 94.34

And now I can calculate its physical dimensions by dividing corresponding pixel dimensions by PPI:

> w<sub>inch</sub> = w<sub>px</sub> / ppi = 1920 / 94.34 = 20.35
>
> h<sub>inch</sub> = h<sub>px</sub> / ppi = 1200 / 94.34 = 12.72

Note that this method will not work for some rare devices that have non-square pixels. It's a case for example with some cheap China-made tablets, but otherwise it's rather uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Like @dirkt said, it’s easy to calculate, using the Pythagorean theorem.

First, you need the aspect ratio:

```
let Ratio = Widthpixels / Heightpixels
```

Then, you just need to calculate:

```
let Widthinches = Ratio * √( (Diagonalinches²) / (Ratio² + 1) )
let Heightinches = √( (Diagonalinches²) / (Ratio² + 1) )
```

This is of course all assuming square physical pixels.